# How to connect to db by piping password

Tags: java, linux

Im trying to connect to database using java...

I used the following snipphet but am unable to connect to db

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ssh -p 4645 username@example.com|send password");
```

Comment: Well what database you use? What driver you use? Have you already added a driver Libaray? Have you anything done...

Comment: But am not able to connect to db......eventhough am using

Comment: I dont know what you mean. At the moment I work with a database and I had to add a driver libary to my project. After that I could connect to the database. It is importent that you use the right driver libary for your database thats the reason I ask you.

Comment: actully that looks more like a ssh connection not a database... @user2552357

Comment: posting your IP, username and password on a public forum on the internet is a bad idea...

Comment: I don't see a password...

Comment: @ThiefMaster It's been removed by Gordon

Comment: @JamieTaylor: I know. I've seen the revision before it had been removed. It just contained username and IP.

Answer (score 2):

for connecting a database you don't need to use **Runtime.getRuntime()** its is use to execute system command in java  for connecting any database in java you have to use its jar file like for and example i want to connect my code to the mysql database the for that i need mysql jar file and calling its lib in my code like:

```
    import java.sql.*;

    class demo
    {
    public static void main(String ar[])throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    Connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename","root", "password");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
     /* 
        your sql query here            
*/
    }
    }
```